# X-frame-options sameorigin error in an iframe from different subdomain using Spring Boot and Angular

Tags: angular, spring-boot, iframe

I'm getting *"Refused to display ' ' in a frame because it set 'X-Frame-Options' to 'sameorigin'"* when trying to show an iframe from a Spring Boot API which is in the same domain as my Angular app but different subdomain (e.g. app.domain.com, api.domain.com).

Why is it not considering the same domain?

Answer (score 1):

**app.domain.com ,  api.domain.com** both are having the same domain but since the subdomain is different it means its a different origin and so Spring security won't allow that by default.

You can add custom header to address the issue like below:

```java
http
    .headers().frameOptions().disable()
    .addHeaderWriter(
        new StaticHeadersWriter("X-FRAME-OPTIONS", "ALLOW-FROM app.domain.com"));
```

Comment: But this custom header is not fully supported by browsers, isn't it?

Comment: Its well supported across all browsers. For reference see the following links https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options  https://www.lambdatest.com/X-Frame-Options-HTTP-header

Comment: If the above solution hellped you, then kindly accept it as solution and upvote if possible.